# How do I install .pkg file intended for MAC?

Tags: software-installation, mac

A private bank has its net-banking facility provided with a software. Only when I install the software I will be able to use the facility. Now they have different versions of the software for Windows and MAC. There is no separate version for Linux. Is it possible to install a .pkg file (which is intended for MAC) in Ubuntu?

Comment: Wine is very good for Windows apps, but there is a program called [Darling](http://www.darlinghq.org/project-status) in development that should be able to do the same for Darwin/Mac apps . Both Darwin and Linux are [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unix_history-simple.svg) systems, so this *could* be quite simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to use a Mac program in Ubuntu (as far as I know of), you can, however, try and get the Windows version working with Wine which lets you run *some* Windows programs on Ubuntu.

> Wine (originally an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator") is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, Mac OSX, & BSD

Install Wine with this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then try to right click the Windows program, choose "Open With > Winw Windows Program Loader".

[Info about Wine here](http://www.winehq.org/about/)

---

Alternatively, you could install Windows into a Virtual Machine, running a full copy of Windows *inside* Ubuntu, (assuming you own a copy of Windows) and run the program in there. You could use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/au/products/player/). This will take a bit more setup.

Comment: hi. Thank you. i installed wine. gave the command 'wincfg' to create a virtual C drive in home. when i start the application using wine (application-name).exe this is what i get.              
sivamoorthy@sivamoorthy-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC:~/Documents$ wine CanSecure-Retail.exe
fixme:winstation:OpenInputDesktop (0,0,10000000): stub
fixme:winstation:OpenInputDesktop (0,0,80000000): stub
fixme:winstation:OpenInputDesktop (0,0,10000000): stub
sivamoorthy@sivamoorthy-HP-Pavilion-dm4-Notebook-PC:~/Documents$

Comment: @SivamoorthyRanjan That I can't help you with, as I don't have any experience with that particular program. Wine wont work flawlessly with all programs, you might need to put a bit of effort in, but then it still might not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, right now there is no working OS X emulator for Linux, however you can use some Windows programs with [Wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine/).

Comment: what is a wine? how should i install it?